# Dealing with warnings / errors in IB with active / deactive constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, ios-autolayout

I have a view that I have made 2 sets of constraints for it. In the code, sometimes I make one set active and the other inactive. During runtime everything works fine, no errors or warnings constraint related. 
 But when I go to IB, I have quite a few errors because of conflicting constraints. 
How can I deal with IB, is there a way to set some setting in IB, so it knows that not all those constraints are meant to be used at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

select your constraint in the IB and then set the priorties according to your need...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwOG.png)

change the priorty to 999 or select a value from the drop down.